# Limit wp_count_posts to the last 7 days

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the total number of posts within a post type, but limit it to the last 7 days.

This is my current code successfully displaying the total amount of posts within the custom post type.

`<?php $published_posts = wp_count_posts($type = 'games')->publish; echo $published_posts;?>`

Is there a way by passing additional arguments? How would one go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`wp_count_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_count_posts/) isn't going to get you there, it's only going to give you a flat number of all of that post_type (and whether it's readable or not).

The [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class seems a bit intimidating at first, but it should get you exactly what you need since it has a lot more granular control built in, namely the [Date Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters).

After initializing `WP_Query`, you can use the `found_posts` property (NOT `post_count`!) to see how many posts it returned. Something like the following:

```
$week_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,    // No limit
    'fields'         => 'ids', // Reduce memory footprint
    'post_type'      => 'your_post_type',
    'date_query'     => array(
        array( 'after' => '1 week ago' )
    )
);

$week_query = new WP_Query( $week_query_args );

echo "We have {$week_query->found_posts} for the past 7 days";
```

Comment: Thank a lot, I figured the WP_Query was overkill for this, but it seems perhaps using even less resources (especially considering it's checking ID's only)?

I came to this solution which works as well. Thank you!

`<?php $querystr = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'games' AND post_date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 7 DAY) LIMIT 0, 30");
                            if (0 < $querystr) $querystr = number_format($querystr); 
                            echo $querystr.' last 7 days';?>`